# Insert html in the middle of xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0

I'm getting troubles. I've got XSLT:

```
<ul class="services-menu">          
        <xsl:apply-templates
                select="items/item[items and not(document(concat('upage://', @id, '.show_on_summary_page_only'))/udata/property/value)]"
                mode="inner_left_col_menu"/>

</ul>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="services-menu">                              
        <li><a href="/page1">Page1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page2">Page2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page3">Page3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to insert my html

```
<li><a href="/page4">Page4</a></li>
```

in the middle after

```
<li><a href="/page1">Page1</a></li>
```

I'm not good in xslt, please anybody help me!

Comment: We really need to see more context. Is the HTML you have shown the input you want to transform or some output your current XSLT creates?

Answer (score 0):

Use another mode if you want to insert another element:

```
<ul class="services-menu">          
        <xsl:apply-templates
                select="items/item[items and not(document(concat('upage://', @id, '.show_on_summary_page_only'))/udata/property/value)]"
                mode="insert_page_4"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates
                select="items/item[items and not(document(concat('upage://', @id, '.show_on_summary_page_only'))/udata/property/value)]"
                mode="inner_left_col_menu"/>


</ul>
```

**References**

- [How to do a second transform on the output of an XSLT template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635593/1113772)
- [Insert element at specific point in output document during XSLT transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701810/1113772)
- [XSLT and temporary documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562817/1113772)